# Extracting Table Data with JSoup on Yahoo Finance

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Trying to practice extracting data from tables using JSoup.  Can't figure out why I can't pull the "Shares Outstanding" field from

https://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=AAPL+Key+Statistics

Here's two attempts where 's' is AAPL:

```
public class YahooStatistics {
String sharesOutstanding = "Shares Outstanding:";

public YahooStatistics(String s)    {
    String keyStatisticsURL = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+s+"+Key+Statistics");

//Attempt 1       
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(keyStatisticsURL).get();

        for (Element table : doc.select("table.yfnc_datamodoutline1"))  {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr"))  {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                for (Element td : tds.select(sharesOutstanding)) {
                    System.out.println(td.ownText());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)   {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

//Attempt 2

    try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(keyStatisticsURL).get();

        for (Element table : doc.select("table.yfnc_datamodoutline1"))    {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr"))   {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                for (int j = 0; j < tds.size() - 1; j++) {
                    Element td = tds.get(j);
                    if ((td.ownText()).equals(sharesOutstanding)) {
                    System.out.println(tds.get(j+1).ownText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex)   {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The attempts return: BUILD SUCCESSFUL and nothing else.

I've disabled JavaScript on my browser and the table still shows, so I'm assuming this is not written in JavaScript but HTML.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes about your source after the edit:

- You should compare `ownText()` rather than `text()`. `text()` gives you the combined text of all the element and all its sub-elements. In this case the element contains `Shares Outstanding<font size="-1"><sup>5</sup></font>:`, so its combined text is `"Shares Outstanding5:"`. If you use `ownText` it will just be `"Shares Outstanding:"`.
- Note the colon (`:`). Update the value in `sharesOutstanding` accordingly.
- You are passing it the wrong URL. There should be a `+` following the `AAPL`.
- Your current query (at least the second attempt) is returning the element twice, because there is a nested table so it finds the TDs twice.

You can either break from your loops once you found a match, go back to your original version (with corrections as above) - see note - or you can try using a more sophisticated query which will only match once:

```
Elements elems = doc.select("td.yfnc_tablehead1:containsOwn("+sharesOutstanding+") + td.yfnc_tabledata1");

if ( ! elems.isEmpty() ) {
    System.out.println( elems.get(0).owntext() );
}
```

This selector gives you all the `td` elements whose class is `yfnc_tabledata1`, whose immediate preceding sibling is a `td` element whose class is `yfnc_tablehead1` and whose own text contains the "Shares Outstanding:" string. This should basically select the exact TD you need.

Note: the previous version of this answer was a long rattle about the difference between `Elements.select()` and `Element.select()`. It turns out that I was dead wrong and your original version should have worked - if you had corrected the four points above. So to set the record straight: `select()` on an `Elements` actually does look inside each element and the resulting list may contain descendents of any of the elements in the original list that match the selection. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to understand but still confused.  The table I'm referencing has "tr" elements and "td" elements.  Also, when I try just changing "Elements" to "Element" above, I return an "incompatible type error".

Comment: Made edits. Hope I'm getting closer.  I'm still not returning anything.

Comment: I understand the Element/Elements difference.  Awesome explanation. ...Made some more edits based on comments and edited explanation.

Comment: @Nikolas Well, now your second attempt works - well it finds the td twice, but that's probably because there is a nested table out there.

Comment: So, I moved it from its own class to the Main, and now I see it.  I also see what you mean about it finding the td twice.  But, this is huge progress, as now I understand what's happening, and I'm acutally returning a value.

Comment: Not seeing the duplication anymore. Thanks.